# Path integral as a partition function (math)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, partition-function

I am reading the following [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(mathematics)), but I am skeptical about what I am reading (it sounds too good to be true). Specifically, I am looking at the passage which states:

> The number of variables $X_i$ need not be countable, in which case the sums are to be replaced by functional integrals. [...]
>
> $$
> Z=\int \mathcal{D}[\phi]\exp (-\beta H[\phi])\,.
> $$

This argument is very interesting. I am only familiar with derivations of the path integral from the usual path/interference then limiting process (for instance as asked in answered in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581810/how-is-the-feynman-path-integral-a-sum-over-paths-and-not-a-product-over-paths)), which is loaded with geometric notions and physical assumptions.

However, the quoted sentence intrigues me deeply because it makes it sound as if the path integral is merely a consequence of having an uncountable number of independent variables, then maximizing the entropy. The form of this distribution (path integral, Gibbs ensemble, etc) is merely a consequence of the properties and quantities of the constraints.

Is this true, or is the page overclaiming? Is there a general proof, perhaps involving the Lagrangian multipliers, which derives the path integral as the distribution that maximizes the entropy subject to uncountably many random variables?

Comment: I am unable to see the link between the text you quoted and the notion of entropy. Pehaps you can clarify?

Comment: @MannyC I am willing to accept that going from discrete to uncountable erases the connection to entropy (for some surely interesting reason), but the article clearly suggests that going from $X_i$ countable to $X_i$ uncountable one gets to path integrals: "The number of variables $X_i$ need not be countable, in which case the sums are to be replaced by functional integrals". Is there a proof that replacing $X_i$ countable to $X_i$ uncountable converts Z (discrete) to Z (path integral)? Or is the article overclaiming, in the sense that more assumption/changes are required to get path integral?

Comment: A “path integral” is just an integral over an uncountable number of variables. They don’t intrinsically have anything to do with paths, or entropy, or anything physical.

Comment: @G.Smith But surely if you start with the Gibbs partition function, then let the number of random variables be uncountable, thus replacing the sum with a functional integral whilst keeping the rest of the structure of the Gibbs partition function, then the previous relation to entropy is maintained --- its still statistical physics but now with uncountably many random variables? Going from countable to uncountable is the only change they have made!

Comment: Yes, that’s how I think of it.